# Illegally mutated the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios4

I'm getting the following exception is thrown under iOS 4.0 but not under 3.0 using core data. I'm populating a tableview controller with data from a core data store. Then drilling down on a row and requesting the details for that row and passing them onto a detail view.

*FATAL ERROR: The persistent cache of section information does not match the current configuration.  You have illegally mutated the NSFetchedResultsController's fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descriptor without either disabling caching or using +deleteCacheWithName:*

Answer (score 22):

Try disabling caching. When you create the `NSFetchedResultsController`, pass `nil` as the cache name.

```
myFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: The fetch request must not be changed if a cache has been set. See this [section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW34) in the documentation. You can either disable the cache or delete it before modifying the predicate.